# make a fullScreen in only layout-land android when play videoView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-videoview

I'm creating android app to play liveStream, I added the videoView in my layout.xml and added the folder of layout-land

I want to make the app shows video full screen in only layout-land not portrait

so I added the following code in onCreate():

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
   {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   } else 
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

but my problem is when I rotate the device it restarts the activity and this lead the stream of video to stop and I want to prevent this. So. I added to manifest this line

```
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

but this leads the code of onCreate() to be executed once only.

How to make my app plays the video stream continuously and when I rotate device to make full screen in layout land then when back to portrait make it normal?

Hope that anyone got my mean.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how u resolved your issue ? below api level19

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add your videoview (or content Parent) as last element in your layout file. and use the next code:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsNotFullscreen; //if you're using RelativeLatout           

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) //To fullscreen
    {
        paramsNotFullscreen=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mVideoView.getLayoutParams();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(paramsNotFullscreen);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params.height=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.width=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);

    } 
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    {
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(paramsNotFullscreen);
    }
}
```

It gets a copy of videoview layoutparams and saves it in a global variable. then creates a new layoutparams object with the previous values but setting now the limits to match_parent and sets it in your videoview. You videoview now is in fullscreen. When you put your device in portrait, paramsNotFullscreen restores previous values.

**UPDATE:**

In your manifest file you must add into Activity declaration the following code to avoid the activity restart:

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

Comment: Call requires API level 19

Comment: @OmidOmidi I tested this code in 2.3+. Anyway I published this answer in 2012 when KitKat was not released yet

Comment: @ClarkXP  uing this code i will not be in need of  layout-land file ? how will i do this my xm layout for video is here attached http://pastie.org/10423424

Comment: You should mention that it's necessary to add  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to the activity in your Manifest to avoid activity to be destroyed and recreated on rotate

Comment: added ;) @gekod, actually you must add also `screenLayout` option

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.create_job_l);

        } 
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.create_job_p);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.create_job_p);
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.create_job_l);
        }


    }
```

Comment: this make the app permanently landScape and this is not my target, I want both landScape and portrait but do full Screen in landScape only.

Comment: after you edited the code, is this will affect the stream of the video? as I prevented the app from restarting the activity when rotate

Comment: you have to define static videoView1 in another class,when change orientation of then you have to set current videoView object in to static videoView1......when restarting the activity at time you have to assign static videoView1 in to current videoView..