# How to hide title bar in android 2.2 programmatically after calling setContentView()?

Tags: android, titlebar

I have make my view in full screen in LANDSCAPE mode just like youtube application.
But had a problem that I am not able to hide title bar in my application.
I am not using sherlock action bar. Instead of that I am using custom Title bar.

1. `getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`
2. `getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`
3. `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

I have used all these three statements. But it doesn't work.

Comment: you should call this before setContentView() what is the requirement to set this after setCOntentView?

Comment: thanks @Tamilselvan actually I have to display activity in full screen mode having no title in landscape mode only.... just like youtube android application player...

Comment: try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033649/1937802 may be helpful to u

Comment: are you using custom action bar

Comment: @Deen yes i am using custom action bar

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide(); try it i hope it may work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Full Screen out onCreate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023023/set-full-screen-out-oncreate)

Comment: @Deen it Doesn't work in 2.2 i have done it...

Comment: actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: @Deen how i get the action bar object in android 2.2 .... where getActionbar() method doesn't work????

Comment: oh k then use holoeverywher theme in your project https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 5):

or in second way you can add in the manifest file then there is no need to add problematically in activity class

```
   <activity
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
         />
```

or you can only in landscape the use this one

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) //To fullscreen
    {
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);

    } 
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    {
        // no need to fullscreen
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but after using this code...my every view has multiple objects....and i m usind videoview so if i am using this my video view will buffer again an i don't want this thing....

Comment: use in manifest file
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"

Comment: i have only one layout for both portrait and landscape due to that i m not use uiMode

Answer (score 2):

use these in `onCreate()` Before `setContentView();`

**like**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Tarsem for reply......BUt i want to hide my action bar after calling setContentView().... in onConfigure method

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before setContentView() !

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with this:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to hide Action Bar on Android 2.2, but none of these solution worked. Everything ends with a crash. I checked the DDMS LOg, It was telling me to use 'Theme.AppCompat'.At last I Solved the problem by changing the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`Line

into `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`and it worked, but the the Interface was dark.

then i tried `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` and finally got what i wanted.

After that when I Searched about 'AppCompat' on [Developer Site I got This.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

So I think the Solution for Android 2.2 is

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And Sorry for my bad English Like Always.

Answer (score 0):

You can define Theme in menifest.xml for full screen.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: thanks for reply @MuhammadAamirALi,Read my question properly Actually I want to change my activity fullscreen notitlebar in landscape mode so if u change in portrait again then title bar is visible to u....

Answer (score -2):

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

This actually work referring to Jorge Freitas, I can't vote him up because i don't have enough "reputation"....